# Transition misbehavior

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I have several problems with transition behavior, probably they are the same single problem.
First class of problems with a short transitions.

```
<style>
.someclass {
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
</style>
<script>
function activationcode()
{
    //$('.someclass').hide(); was in display none state.
    $('.someclass').css('opacity', 0);
    $('.someclass').show();
    $('.someclass').css('opacity', 1);
}
</script>
```

Add in most of cases this code doesn't work as expected.  The `.someclass` item appears in final state.  The changing property doesn't matter, `opacity` is just for example.  To make it working the two things helps: a) changing `all` for transition to the particular property, for this example to `opacity`; b) call `$('.someclass').css('opacity', 1);` with delay, for example, 100ms.
But this only reduce probability of problem to very low value, doesn't fix it.

Second class of problem is for a long animation.  It works, but if you put it inside the tab (or anything like that), and will start to switch from animated tab to other one, the animation may be finished in a final state before the specified time.  Single switch/switch-back usually doesn't break animation.  But two or more switches does with very high probability.

I can reproduce this on Firefox (not very recent).  Initially was reported for Chrome (reporter states that he uses the last one version).

I suspect that the problem does depend on amount of css/js activity on page (was unable to reproduce second problem with minimal jsfiddle).

So the question is how to fix such problems, does any solution exist?

Comment: You forget `:` after `transition` ?

Answer (score 0):

Place the line...

```
$('.someclass').css('opacity', 1);
```

...in a `setTimeout(fn, 0)`. This will defer its execution, ensuring that the browser won't optimise those steps into one paint (show the element at 100% opacity).

Comment: I do so, but in some cases it looks like even 100ms delay I usually use not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use classes instead and handle show/hide in CSS only

```
.hide {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s linear 0s, display 0s linear 1s;
    /* decrease opacity, then change display with a delay */
}
.show {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: display 0s linear 0s, opacity 1s linear 0s;
    /* change display instantly without delay, then increase opacity */
}
```

By delaying the hiding for 1s, you allow the opacity transition to complete before hiding it.
But we reset the delay on the showing because we need people to see the opacity increasing.

Comment: Does this technic needs the setTimeout workaround?  I didn't specially test, but it looks that problem was not only while setting opacity to 1 just after setting opacity to 0 to trigger transition.  The hight probability was that problem also occurred while browser was busy with other activity on the page.

Comment: You don't need any timeout for this to work. The fourth parameter is the delay of the transition and we use it to let the disappearing occur before fully hiding the block. Just change the class of the element with JS. The navigator will handle itself the transition even if busy doing something else. It's a lot smoother than doing it with JS anyway as the browser can optimize it itself.

Comment: What about tab switch, do you have any idea?

Comment: If you just use JS to add/remove classes and let the browser do the animations using CSS, it should fix the issue too.